# Another method to Clear cookie when logging out using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to clear cookie while logging out of a page using javascript, other than

```
expires="the time stamp";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. `expires=Sun, 15 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC;`.

Comment: Very specific date you've got there, @VisioN! To continue on from what you've said above, setting the `expires` property to any time in the past will clear the cookie - the 15th of December 2013 isn't some magical cookie-clearing date. ;-)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly It was a reply to the initial author's solution, check in the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26255536/1) :)

Comment: thanks for the comments. I am not asking for a specific date. My question is to know whether there is any other method to clear cookies rather than giving a specific date and time.  To be more specific  I want to clear the cookies immediately when a person being logs out of a page

Comment: @giya But what is wrong with setting `expires` to past date?

Comment: oh ok. got the exact concept of expires. if we set a passed date the cookie will be cleared. :)

Comment: @giya No, cookie will be definitely removed immediately if new `expires` parameter is less than current date/time. So you may entirely rely on this.

Comment: yes.Got it now. thanks a lot @ VisioN

Comment: @ VisioN `document.cookie = "phase=" + graphType + " " + "start=" + fromDate + " " + "end=" + toDate + ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";` This is the code i used to clear the cookie. I am  afraid that i did some mistakes in the format.Could you please help me?